# How to import an unversioned directory in to local repository in smartsvn?

Tags: svn, version-control, smartsvn

I'm starting to use SmartSVN and I can't import a directory to a local repository. It gives me the error shown in the figure.
[image]

I have already configured **c:\repo** as the local directory but I don't know how to choose it in this step in the *Import Into Repository* dialog.

Could anybody tell me then how to select my local repository to import my projects?

Comment: You have already tried plain old `c:\repo` or `c:\\repo`?

Answer (score 2):

SmartSVN [does not support the Local Repository Access (aka file://) protocol](http://www.wandisco.com/smartsvn/faq).  You'll need to start a server to use the repository on your local machine.

Based on your screenshot you appear to be using Windows.  Probably the easiest process would be to [download the Windows Vanilla Subversion installer from WANdisco](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#windows).  Once that's installed you should be able to start up svnserve from the command prompt like so:

```
svnserve -d -r c:\repo
```

Then you'll be able to access the repository via `svn://127.0.0.1/` in SmartSVN.  If svnserve is stopped or the computer is restarted you'll need to repeat this process.  If you want a more permanent setup I'd suggest setting up [svnserve as a service on Windows which is covered in the SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.invoking.winservice).